# What is the difference between using jQuery and plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can somebody explain to me what the difference is between these two examples:

```
var obj = getElementById("id1"); // without jQuery
var obj = $("#id1"); // with jQuery
```

Is the returned value in both cases the same object?

Comment: One difference is that the second one takes about 10 times longer to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById()` returns a DOM element only, `$("#id1")` returns a jQuery object containing DOM element(s).